# Multi-type lists

Tags: list, types, f#

I build a function that, given a composed list, returns two lists:

```
let rec split2 l =
    match l with 
    [] -> ([], [])
    | (x, y)::ls -> let (xs, ys) =
                                split ls in (x::xs, y::ys);;  

val split2 : l:('a * 'b) list -> 'a list * 'b list

lsts = [('a', 1); ('b', 2); ('c', 3); ('d', 4)]

split2 lsts;;
val it : int list * char list = ([1; 2; 3; 4], ['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'])
```

Now, I applied the concept with a more complex list:

```
let l1 = [('a', 1, 'a'); ('b', 2, 'b'); ('c', 3, 'c'); ('d', 4, 'd')]
```

The function I used gave problems with types, so I build a second one. In this case, I have carefully defined the types, but it still returns an error when applied to `l1`, even if it compiles.

```
let rec split3 (l:(char * int * char) list) =                  
    match l with 
    [] -> ([], [], [])
    | (x, y, z)::ls -> 
                    let (xs, ys, zs) = 
                                    split3 ls in (xs, ys, zs);; 

val split3 : l:(char * int * char) list -> 'a list * 'b list * 'c list

split3 l1;;

    error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has been inferred to 
    have generic type val it : '_a list * '_b list * '_c list    
    Either define 'it' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit 
arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.
```

Why, even if the types are declared, it requires a further type annotation?

Comment: Yes indeed. That made me consider a second question: what is the difference with the 'two elements' list in the first example and the 'three elements' list in the second? They both are composed by characters and integers, afterall.

Comment: Sorry my first comment was irrelevant. Compiler cannot infer returning type of the function. You can make it explicit: `let rec split3 (l:(char * int * char) list) : (char list * int list * char list) = `

Comment: More on Value restriction error as it sometimes hard to understand: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/

Comment: These functions already exist in the core F# library; they're called `List.unzip` and `List.unzip3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer**

The function you are looking for already exists in `FSharp.Core` as [`List.unzip3`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.unzip3%5B't1,'t2,'t3%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)

```
List.unzip3 : ('T1 * 'T2 * 'T3) list -> 'T1 list * 'T2 list * 'T3 list
```

**Long Answer**

The two functions you've described are different.  Notice that in the type signature of the `split3` function is:

```
val split3 : l:(char * int * char) list -> 'a list * 'b list * 'c list
```

This doesn't make sense.  The type signature should be:

```
val split3 : l:(char * int * char) list -> char list * int list * char list
```

So, why isn't it?

Notice that in the your `split2` function, you've defined the result as `(x::xs, y::ys)` and in `split3` you've defined the result as `(xs, ys, zs)`.  That means the result of your `split3` function is always `([], [], [])` but the type of the empty lists isn't defined - hence the value restriction error.

This is trivial to fix:

```
let rec split3 (l:(char * int * char) list) =                  
    match l with 
    | [] -> ([], [], [])
    | (x, y, z)::ls -> 
        let (xs, ys, zs) = split3 ls
        (x::xs, y::ys, z::zs)
```

Once you've corrected this, you can remove the type annotations as the type of the function will now be correctly inferred:

```
let rec split3 l =                  
    match l with 
    | [] -> ([], [], [])
    | (x, y, z)::ls -> 
        let (xs, ys, zs) = split3 ls
        (x::xs, y::ys, z::zs)
```

---

Further, this type of function is just a `fold` so if you were to write it manually, it would be better to write it in terms of that higher-order function  rather than via an explicit recursion.

```
let split3 l =
    let folder (x, y, z) (xs, ys, zs) =
        (x::xs, y::ys, z::zs)
    List.foldBack folder l ([], [], [])
```

Note that I'm using `foldBack` rather than `fold` to preserve the original list order.

Comment: Straightforward and instructive. Thank you for the wonderful answer! Just a detail: is `in` unnecessary? And, as stated in the comments, a list should not have a homogeneous type?

Comment: @Worice One of the differences between the lightweight and verbose syntax in F# is the requirement for `in`, `begin` and `end` (verbose) vs use of indentation (lightweight).  Lightweight syntax is the default and almost all F# you'll ever see uses it so `in` is almost always unnecessary.   See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/verbose-syntax

Comment: Thank you, that is something I missed!